# Как лучше и быстрее всего передать первый массив данных клиенту

Tags: php, javascript, json, websocket

Есть сайт, база данных и PHP прослойка. Надо передать клиенту первый JSON массив данных, а потом его обновлять через сокет. До этого использовал AJAX запрос на PHP скрипт. Есть ли более быстрые и удачные реализации этой передачи?

Comment: Всё зависит от вашей задачи. Из вопроса непонятно для каких целей вы это делаете

Comment: @ArchDemon Сайт специализируется на лайв трансляциях, лайв счет парсится с другого сайта, как только он меняется через сокет передается новое значение. Но когда человек открывает страницу ему нужно передать все текущие результаты из базы.

Comment: В вашем случае достаточно ajax. И раз в n секунд делать запрос серверу на предмет обновлений. Но если вам нужна скорость обновления данных или не хотите бомбить сервер постоянными опросами, то тут сразу на websocket. Могу посоветовать вам оба варианта. Начать с простого для вас. У каждого решения есть проблемы с производительностью

Comment: @ArchDemon интересно какие проблемы с производительностью у ws?

Comment: @Вадим, например, 1000000 - 100000000 соединений.

Comment: @ArchDemon ты серьёзно?  для ws это не проблема. на один порт http -65535 портов/соединений ws , добавить http порты не проблема, 1000000/65535 примерно 15 портов. память ныне не проблема. количество ядер тоже. держать такое количество соединений - не проблема, а вот обрабатывать - ну да, только вот для 1000000++ одновременных клиентов уровень явно не хостинга, только если сравнивать такие нагрузки ws и ajax - то в этом сравнении сервер с ws будет просто курящим бамбук, а с ajax рабом на галерах.

Comment: @Вадим Доброго вечера! Прошу прощения, а Вы не могли бы предложить Ваш вариант решения моего вопроса?)

Comment: @AtCliff_ без проблем. как связаться? только сервер у меня на java. если  честно, php для этих целей мало подходит, демоны его - это велосипеды...

Comment: @Вадим если с Вами можно пообщаться по этому вопросу, был бы благодарен, если напишите на почту vistecter@yandex.ru.